# get downloadURL in react native after uploading image

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I have a uploadImage function:

```
    const [profileURL, setProfileURL] = useState("")

    uploadImage = async (uri, userUID) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri)
        const blob = await response.blob()
        var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("avatar/" + userUID)
        await ref.put(blob, {contentType:'image/jpg'}).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        await ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            setProfileURL(url)
        })
    }
```

The upload part is working, the image is saved to firebase storage correctly, But Im trying to get the downloadURL of the image and set it in state `setProfileURL({ uri: url})`

I then call a handleSubmit function which calls this upload function:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        await this.uploadImage(imageOne, firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid).then(
            setCurrentUserDetails(
                { ...currentUserDetails, 
                    name, 
                    age: Number(age), 
                    height,
                    profileURL,
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

Everything else is updated but this profileURL field doesn't get updated. When I log the state variable on the uploadImage function I get the following:

```
setProfileURL in upload function [Function bound dispatchAction]
profileURL in upload function
```

Ii have tried `setProfileURL(String(url))` But can't get this DonwnloadURL to save.

I also tried:

```
uploadImage = async (uri, userUID) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri)
        const blob = await response.blob()
        var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("avatar/" + userUID)
        await ref.put(blob, {contentType:'image/jpg'}).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        const url = await ref.getDownloadURL().catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        console.log("URL", url);
        setProfileURL(String(url))
        return url
    }
```

which does log out the correct url:

```
URL https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/MY_URL_HERE
```

just doesn't seem to update the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates are not synchronous. From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
> callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
> state, read about the updater argument below.

So by the time `setCurrentUserDetails`, `profileURL` is not updated. The second approach should work for getting the correct URL. But instead of using `profileURL`, you can use the returned url value directly from the method.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const url = await this.uploadImage(
    imageOne,
    firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid
  );

  setCurrentUserDetails({
    ...currentUserDetails,
    name,
    age: Number(age),
    height,
    profileURL: url,
  });
};
```